# bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails Display Issues

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this gem to try and get a datetime picker for one of my fields:
https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails

In particular from the example documentation (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#no-icon-input-field-only) i'm using the No Icon (input field only).

When I select the fields a pop-up appears but nothing appears in the dialogue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJSEr.jpg, so i suspect that either a CSS or JS isnt loading properly....

Gemfile

```
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.47'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'jquery-minicolors-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.minicolors
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

application.css.scss

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.minicolors
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

races.coffee

```
$ -> $('input#race_raceDate').datetimepicker();
```

races/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :raceDate, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :raceDate, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:raceDate) %>
  </div>
```

Firefox Debug Console

```
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-inner-spin-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:243:17
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-search-cancel-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:255:17
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-file-upload-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:261:2
Unknown property 'orphans'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:347:11
Unknown property 'widows'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:348:10
Unknown property 'touch-action'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:535:18
Expected colour but found 'auto'.  Expected colour but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:567:15
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:990:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:991:11
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-expand'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:2795:15
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:2807:15
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:2811:14
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:2815:15
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-value'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:2834:27
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3065:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3066:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3083:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3084:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3096:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3097:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3132:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3133:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3158:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3159:13
Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3193:21
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3820:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3821:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3859:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3860:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3946:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:3947:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4020:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4021:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4044:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4045:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4181:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4182:11
Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4233:21
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4265:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4266:11
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-value'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4304:22
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-expand'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4315:16
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4342:10
Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4361:21
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4393:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4394:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4494:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4495:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4521:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4522:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4623:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4624:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4634:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4635:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4683:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4684:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4694:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4695:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4743:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4744:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4754:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4755:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4803:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4804:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4814:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4815:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4860:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4861:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4871:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4872:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4970:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:4971:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5220:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5221:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5230:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5231:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5253:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5254:13
Unknown property 'column-count'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5313:24
Unknown property 'column-gap'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5316:22
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5367:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5368:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5677:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5678:11
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5697:20
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5710:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5711:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5727:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5728:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5763:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:5764:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6087:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6088:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6122:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6123:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6152:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6153:11
Unknown property 'line-break'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6209:12
Unknown property 'line-break'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6315:12
Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-transform-3d'. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6489:8
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6520:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6521:11
Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-transform-3d'. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6532:8
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6582:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6583:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6643:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6644:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6904:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6905:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6911:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6912:11
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6949:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6950:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6956:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6957:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6994:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:6995:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7001:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7002:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7039:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7040:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7046:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7047:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7084:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7085:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7091:13
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:7092:13
Error in parsing value for 'position'.  Declaration dropped. 1st_load_framework.self-121b0e7d75d75ef1c412bbc0b62dd3e1d70399473685e70c79dcc9707c360cd0.css:8274:12
Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)
Tooltip<()
 tooltip.self-dd8a9f3fa1f9fc58df30c7ed9a17dfc7303b812d72640899beee03609124b426.js:21
<anonymous>
 tooltip.self-dd8a9f3fa1f9fc58df30c7ed9a17dfc7303b812d72640899beee03609124b426.js:14
 tooltip.self-dd8a9f3fa1f9fc58df30c7ed9a17dfc7303b812d72640899beee03609124b426.js:21:1
TypeError: Tooltip is undefined
Popover<()
 popover.self-7d459fac34d4d96fd9d6da8efcd40dee55b66579a24ddcebf0a355c82dcad7e0.js:32
<anonymous>
 popover.self-7d459fac34d4d96fd9d6da8efcd40dee55b66579a24ddcebf0a355c82dcad7e0.js:18
 popover.self-7d459fac34d4d96fd9d6da8efcd40dee55b66579a24ddcebf0a355c82dcad7e0.js:32:7
```

Comment: open the js console on the browser and see if there are errors js errors or 404

Comment: I've edited the question with this information

Comment: where you add bootstrap css?

Comment: @inye, a seperate css file, bootstrap is loading OK as the styling works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be something I really wished I had spotted. I am running bootstrap 4 where the gem expects bootstrap 4.

Adding gem 'bootstrap-sass' fixes this but you do loose bootstrap 4 functionality

Answer (score -1):

ok, so you just need to add tether before bootstrap js on your code, for example

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

this was just an example, for your case, that you are adding bootstrap on your application.js file, try with this.

download tether.min.js to your local, add it to the respective folder on your app and then change your application.js file adding this require

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tether.min
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.minicolors
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't made any difference

Comment: Correction, messed up my application.js imports. Now the tether error is gone but the datetime picker looks the same

Comment: Perhaps something to do with the way bootstrap is imported? I used rails composer